# Directly access nested linklist in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a my menu navigation set up like this in shopify:

```
- main_menu
    - top_level_1
    - top_level_2
        - top_level_2_sub_menu_1
        - top_level_2_sub_menu_2
        - top_level_2_sub_menu_3
```

I am able to do this to iterate through all the menu items:

```
    {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
        <p>{{ link.handle }}</p>
        {% for nestedLink in link.links %}
            <p>{{ nestedLink.handle }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

However I don't seem to be able to iterate JUST through the submenus belonging to top_level_2. I have tried this with no success:

```
{% for link in linklists.main-menu.top_level_2.links %}
    <p>{{ link.handle }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And also tried this:

```
{% for link in linklists.top_level_2.links %}
    <p>{{ link.handle }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to directly get a handle to linklist in order to iterate through its child links? Or would I need to first find that link by searching the top level items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`linklists.main-menu.links` returns an array of object items.

A.k.a:

```
[
  {
    active: false
    child_active: false
    current: false
    child_current: false
    levels: 1
    links: [...]
    object: null
    title: "Some title"
    type: "http_link"
    url: "#:
  },
  {
    active: false
    child_active: false
    current: false
    child_current: false
    levels: 1
    links: [...]
    object: null
    title: "Some title"
    type: "http_link"
    url: "#:
  },
  {
    active: false
    child_active: false
    current: false
    child_current: false
    levels: 1
    links: [...]
    object: null
    title: "Some title"
    type: "http_link"
    url: "#:
  },
  etc...
]
```

So you can't say `linklists.main-menu.top_level_2` since there is no such object.

You can say `linklists.main-menu.links[1].links` and do something like so:

```
{%- for link in linklists.main-menu.links[1].links -%}

{%- endfor -%}
```

But please note that this will loop only the items in the second navigation item and ignore the rest.

Comment: Btw, how do you debug this thing?  like how you console.log in liquid to know what exactly is getting returned?

Comment: @VladSofronov linklist doesn't allow to pass `| json` to show the response, so you will have to refer to the docs. Or you can just go in the admin and add the `.json` to the menu URL to show the response for example `/menus/116488306759.json`.

Comment: what's the full url for this hack? like what goes before /menus?

Comment: @VladSofronov You just go to your menu in your admin and add `.json` at the end of it. The full url will be something like so: `https://admin.shopify.com/store/YOUR_STORE_NAME/menus/MENU_ID.json`

Comment: Oh, wow - black magic:)))